# create a LAN with wireless uplink

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have 5 IP devices that I need to be joined into a LAN (lanA). And I need this LAN to be connected wirelessly to the (wireless) router (lanB).

So that my LAN of 5 IP devices appears as a single IP to the outside network (routerX network).

Devices of lanA use static IP addresses.

So basically I need a NAT-capable device that has wired connection to my devices, and wireless uplink connection to the main LAN. Are there routers that can be configured this way?

Comment: doesn't the router on LAN-B function as a NAT firewall? if so than all you're really looking for is a router or access point that can operate in bridge mode for LAN-A, right?

Comment: I need to hide my (lanA) devices from lanB. lanA shall be a subnet, not a segment of the lanB. So what I need is a wireless router with Client Router mode. (this is the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy any DD-WRT compatible router, and use bridged mode.  You may already have a compatible router.

[You can check router compatibility here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database)

[Here's a list of supported devices](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices)

[Instructions for setting up bridged mode](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged)

DD-WRT is a custom firmware, based on Linux, that runs on many cheap and popular routers.  It gives the router the functionality of network devices costing thousands of dollars.

Comment: bridged mode (client bridge) will add my devices to the lanB LAN. What I need is DD-WRT "Client Mode" (or "Client Router" mode).